# HtmlUnit and Java eclipse errors not running correctly

Tags: java, htmlunit

So , I am completely new to Java this is my first program. I'm working with Java Eclipse using HtmlUnit and Mars i believe for my Eclipse

and this is my current code of what i've tried

```
public static void webstart(String website) throws InterruptedException
{
    try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.getDefault())) 
    {
            label1.setText("Status: Loading Light Viewer...");
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(website);
            label1.setText("Status: Clicking Start Viewer...");
            HtmlElement start = (HtmlElement) page.getByXPath("//*[@id='main_page_offline']/div/div[3]/div/div/a");
            start.click();
            label1.setText("Status: Clicked...");
            i=2;
            while(i==2)
            {
                HtmlElement text = (HtmlElement) page.getByXPath("//*[@id='visio_compteur']");
                String time = text.toString();
                timer(time);
            }
    } 
    catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e) 
    {

            e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
}
```

It crashes after writing Loading Light Viewer... to the label.

Here is the errors I'm currently getting

```
    Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: syntax error (script in www.websitehere.com from (289, 32) to (291, 10)#290)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:865)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:701)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:718)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:945)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:351)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:411)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:270)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1040)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:253)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:199)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:476)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:350)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
        at websync.websyn.webstart(websyn.java:110)
        at websync.websyn$1.widgetSelected(websyn.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
        at websync.websyn.open(websyn.java:56)
        at websync.websyn.main(websyn.java:40)
    Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (script in www.websitehere.com/ from (289, 32) to (291, 10)#290)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:66)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:187)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:254)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:243)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:236)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Parser.java:2816)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Parser.java:2388)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2292)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2219)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2205)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2188)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2165)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2139)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2130)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2121)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2112)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2103)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2094)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2060)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2033)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.variables(Parser.java:1878)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1009)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:926)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:570)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:491)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2661)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1624)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:202)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1616)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:692)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
        ... 41 more
    Enclosed exception: 
    net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException: syntax error (script in www.websitehere.com/ from (289, 32) to (291, 10)#290)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter.error(StrictErrorReporter.java:66)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:187)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addError(Parser.java:167)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:254)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:243)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.reportError(Parser.java:236)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.primaryExpr(Parser.java:2816)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.memberExpr(Parser.java:2388)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.unaryExpr(Parser.java:2292)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.mulExpr(Parser.java:2219)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.addExpr(Parser.java:2205)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.shiftExpr(Parser.java:2188)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.relExpr(Parser.java:2165)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.eqExpr(Parser.java:2139)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitAndExpr(Parser.java:2130)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitXorExpr(Parser.java:2121)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.bitOrExpr(Parser.java:2112)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.andExpr(Parser.java:2103)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.orExpr(Parser.java:2094)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.condExpr(Parser.java:2060)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.assignExpr(Parser.java:2033)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.variables(Parser.java:1878)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statementHelper(Parser.java:1009)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.statement(Parser.java:926)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:570)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Parser.parse(Parser.java:491)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileImpl(Context.java:2661)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1624)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$TimeoutContext.compileString(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:202)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.compileString(Context.java:1616)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:692)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.compile(JavaScriptEngine.java:701)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:718)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:945)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:351)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:411)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:270)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
        at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1040)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:253)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:199)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:476)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:350)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
        at websync.websyn.webstart(websyn.java:110)
        at websync.websyn$1.widgetSelected(websyn.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
        at websync.websyn.open(websyn.java:56)
        at websync.websyn.main(websyn.java:40)
    == CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

    var add_target=;
```

Comment: Try `new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME))` or `FIREFOX_38`, otherwise provide your URL. You can also read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an error in site's JavaScript.

Haven't you tried this setting?

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

before

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(website);
```